# How can I store Object in Enum in Java

Tags: java, enums

With the Spigot-API, in Minecraft, I want to check if the Player is holding a specific Item in his hand.
Can I somehow get the Item as comparative value from an Enum?
I want to do that because I have some special Items with custom meta data and I want to have them in a enumeration list. Is this an eligible way? I tried something with a constructor in the enum but also I am too inexperienced in enums. -Or what would be a good way to store the items?

I just want to get the Item by doing: `Items.NAME;`

Would this be a solution?

```
public enum Items{
GRANADE (getGranade());

ItemStack item;
Items(ItemStack item) {
    this.item = item;
}

private static ItemStack getGranade() {
    //some code here
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is the [Material  Enum](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Material.html) in the Spigot API, you can just use .getType() on the ItemStack to get the Material of it. But this does not include the meta data.

You could create your own enum like this:

```
    public enum SpecialItems(){
    ITEM1(new ItemStack(Material.ACACIA_BOAT));

    private ItemStack itemStack;
    public SpecialItems(ItemStack itemStack){
        this.itemStack = itemStack;
    }

    public ItemStack getItemStack(){
        return itemStack;
    }

}
```

You would get the ItemStack like this:

```
SpecialItems.ITEM1.getItemStack();
```

In the construtor you can add other values if you want to. But i think this peace of code should demonstrate probably how the concept works, otherwise take a look at the explanation of an enum by java: [Java Explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).
Further, the get method should not be static beauce every enumarted thing in your enum is an object (/ an instance of the enum) and without static your method operates on the object. But the variable you want to return with the get method is only accable by the object, thus you don not want to use static in this method.

But be careful with compairing the ItemStacks of the enum and of the player hand because the ItemStack includes the amount of Items.

Comment: Thank you.

I knew the static thing isn't right. I had to make the method static though because Eclipse told me to do so.. I don't know.

I kinda hoped it not to be `SpecialItems.ITEM1.getItemStack();` . I wanted to get the object only from saying `SpecialItems.ITEM1` I thought this would return the ItemStack just like you can do Material.ACACIA_BOAT which returns a Material.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to use `SpecialItems.ITEM1.getItemStack()`. But you could write a method like `public static boolean isSpecialItem(SpecialItems item, ItemStack stack)`or what else do you need and in the method you can then use `item.getItemStack()`. Then if you need to know if an item is one of your special items you just have to call this method.

Comment: Of course.
Anyways, thanks for your effort and Help!